# need help joining two tables with a having count clause

Tags: join, group-by, count

I am a network guy so I apologize for this.... I have two tables I need to join and pull names out of.  pt_basic has the patient names and codes I need, ptc_diagnosis has their diagnosis.  I need to pull the names of patients who have one and only one diagnosis.  I can join the tables on patient_id.  here is what i wrote:

```
select 
PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID, 
PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST 
from PTC_DIAGNOSIS 
inner join PT_BASIC on PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID=PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
where PTC_DIAGNOSIS.create_date>'12/01/2015' 
group by PTC_DIAGNOSIS.patient_id 
having COUNT(*)=1
```

I get the error `Column 'PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

I have moved columns around, tried having pt_basic first and re-written it 15 different ways with similar errors every time.  i feel i am close, but maybe not.

thank you

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If this is SQL Server then your error message contains the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

very close only the GROUP BY Columns forgotten

Try this:

```
select 
PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID, 
PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST 
from PTC_DIAGNOSIS 
inner join PT_BASIC on PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID=PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
where PTC_DIAGNOSIS.create_date>'12/01/2015' 
group by 
PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID, 
PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST 
having COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: thank you, but it didn't quite return what I needed.  I get patients with more than one diagnosis.   i think we could take out the where clause as that date really doesn't matter as long as i can get patients with only one diagnosis.

Comment: taking the where clause out seems to be giving me the right information now, I just have to find a way to narrow the patients to a time frame.  i may have to join another table to the mix that has admission dates

Comment: ok i added this to help narrow the results, but whenever i have any date column in the query, it is ignored.  for example, i have the last cert column in the one i wrote below but it returns patients with certifications from 2014 and 2013.  if i take the date column out the query runs great, just with too much info

Comment: select 
PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID, 
PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST 
from PTC_DIAGNOSIS 
inner join PT_BASIC on PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID=PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
where PT_BASIC.DATASET_ID='26' or PT_BASIC.DATASET_ID='31' and PT_BASIC.last_certification_DATE>'2015-03-01 00:00:00'
group by 
PTC_DIAGNOSIS.PATIENT_ID, 
PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_FIRST, 
PT_BASIC.NAME_LAST 
having COUNT(*)=1

Comment: what column type is the `PT_BASIC.last_certification_DATE`? if timestamp or date you can use the [Date/Time Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) or append `::date` to the column (to "switch" the type) Like `select now();` = full timestamp or `select now()::date`= date only or `select now()::date -1' = yesterday and so on...

Comment: @ScottJones: That seems to be a completely different story. When you have a new question, please [post it as such](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

As [Patrick7 has already said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134533/6965), you need your GROUP BY to include all the non-aggregated columns that are in your SELECT list.

In your case, however, there is a way to avoid duplicating all the SELECT columns in GROUP BY. You could first aggregate the *PTC_DIAGNOSIS* rows separately:

```
SELECT
  patient_id
FROM
  PTC_DIAGNOSIS 
WHERE
  create_date > '20151201'     -- or '20150112', whatever that '12/01/2015' means
GROUP BY
  patient_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*)=1
```

then use that query as a derived table and join it to *PT_BASIC*:

```
SELECT
  p.PATIENT_ID,
  p.PATIENT_CODE, 
  p.NAME_FIRST, 
  p.NAME_LAST 
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      PATIENT_ID
    FROM
      PTC_DIAGNOSIS 
    WHERE
      create_date > '20151201'     -- or '20150112', whatever that '12/01/2015' means
    GROUP BY
      patient_id
    HAVING
      COUNT(*)=1
  ) AS d
  INNER JOIN PT_BASIC AS p ON d.PATIENT_ID = p.PATIENT_ID
;
```

The result would be the same as with Patrick's query, and this way you can include as many *PT_BASIC* columns into the output as you like without having to duplicate them in another clause.

Additional notes:

- Use short table aliases for better readability.
- [Use locale-/culture-independent date formats for date or date & time literals](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), like *`YYYYMMDD`* for dates and *`YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS.nnn…`* or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.nnn…` for datetimes.
  Otherwise, no-one will be sure what `'12/01/2015'` means. Is it `12th-Jan-2015` or `Dec-1st-2015`? Most importantly, the engine may translate it to any of those dates, depending on various (connection, database and server) settings.
- [End your SQL statements with a semicolon](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).